# apache zeppelin hive jdbc mapreduce java.sql.SQLException

Tags: mapreduce, hive, apache-zeppelin

JDBC interpreter for hive in Zeppelin works fine on non MR queries. In case of MR, getting the below error

%Hive
select * from table where month=2;

getting the below exception :
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:577)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:660)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:489)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I am not familiar with JDBC interpreter, but in this case it would be easier to investigate errors if you describe environment more. For example, Zeppelin Version, Hive Version, JDBC interpreter settings and so on.

Comment: Zeppelin version 0.7, Hive server 2 running on CDH-5.4.0,all dependencies resolved from cloudera parcels.
connection string jdbc:hive2://<<hostname>>:10000/default